# Error 'A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.'

Tags: list, flutter, dart

A value of type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

```
// Get Channel
var response = await http.get(uri, headers: headers);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body)['items'][0] ;
  Channel channel = Channel.fromMap(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.decode(response.body)` returns data of type Map<String, dynamic>.

If your response.body['items'][0] is also Map<String, dynamic>, you should cast it `json.decode(response.body)['items'][0] as Map<String, dynamic>`